# MsSQL to MySQL Migration

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

I am trying to get all data from a table out of a MsSQL Database to import it into MySQL. Looking at guides it should be simple enough.

I choose Tasks -> Export Data
Then i choose the..

..source as MsSQL Server Native client

..target as flat file (Locale=Danish and tick the Unicode checkbox)

..delimited by " (Double Quote)

..to remove the headers

..row delimiter as {CR}{LF} (Which is \r\n in MySQL?)

..column delimiter as , (comma)

And the run it immediately -> results in a file called test.csv

I go "Script table as" to get all the columns and their atributes, copy that into MySQL Workbench and adapt the code to the create format of MySQL.

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\test.txt' INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
;`

And then i get the following error:

Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8 character string: ''

This i don't really understand since i've exported into unicode. Any ideas?

Comment: have you ever hear about **MSSA**? it is a tool that you would do this easily. more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/sql-server-migration-assistant)

Comment: Nope, but i am also going the other way. MsSQL -> MySQL and as fas as i can read the MSSA is MySQL -> MsSQL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure its formatting issue and best way is to do a script.

- Connect database using `ODBC` and `PHP` (if you are using PHP), `odbc_connect` for example `Conn1`
- Connect database using `mysqli` and `PHP` `mysqli_connect` for example `Conn2`
- Get each record in array or object with connecting `Conn1`
- Now insert record in `Conn2`

I hope it will help you.
Thanks

Comment: I am not a PHP programmer, I Dabble a bit with Python but not sure i'm skilled enough to make what you are suggesting. As far as i can understand, MsSQL is default latin-1, so i am thinking about exporting as that and the convert in import, is this an option?

Comment: Well, for that you need to load driver of MS Sql and MySQL in python and you can do. 
Regarding formatting, yes you are right. You can try that too.